# Xorg and Xserver not starting up after hibernate

Tags: xorg, x-server

I'm currently running Mint 14 on this computer, but it also previously happened with Fedora 16 so I'm guessing it's a general problem with my drivers.

The display will not start up after the laptop hibernates. If I close the lid it will just show a weird snowy display from which I need to reboot, If I don't close the lid it will show some errors and take me to the console where i can reboot.

The log files are pretty massive, but I've pulled out the bits that looked to give the most vital information. It looks most likely a driver issue and I've been to http://wiki.x.org/ to have a hunt around but it's not really something I'm familiar with.

Running lsmod | grep nouveau

```
nouveau               895609  3 
ttm                    83595  1 nouveau
drm_kms_helper         46784  1 nouveau
drm                   275528  5 nouveau,ttm,drm_kms_helper
i2c_algo_bit           13413  1 nouveau
mxm_wmi                12979  1 nouveau
video                  19335  1 nouveau
wmi                    19070  3 asus_wmi,nouveau,mxm_wmi
```

Running lspci

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1251 (rev a1)
```

/var/log/syslog:

```
Jan  2 18:13:30 user-G74Sx mdm[1586]: WARNING: Failed to start X server several times in a short time period; disabling display :0
```

/var/log/X.org.log:

```
[    23.428] 
X.Org X Server 1.13.0
Release Date: 2012-09-05
[    23.428] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    23.428] Build Operating System: Linux 3.2.0-30-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[    23.428] Current Operating System: Linux user-G74Sx 3.5.0-17-generic #28-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 9 19:31:23 UTC 2012 x86_64
[    23.428] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.5.0-17-generic root=UUID=e7c94e41-c243-45b2-9cdc-e851b5cf16d0 ro quiet splash
[    23.428] Build Date: 08 October 2012  03:34:01PM
[    23.428] xorg-server 2:1.13.0-0ubuntu6 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[    23.428] Current version of pixman: 0.26.0
[    23.429]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    23.429] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
(++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
(WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    23.429] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Wed Jan  2 18:15:32 2013
[    23.438] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    23.439] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[    23.439] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[    23.439] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[    23.439] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[    23.439] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
Using a default monitor configuration.
[    23.440] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    23.440] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    23.440] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[    23.440] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    23.440]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    23.440] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[    23.440]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    23.440] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[    23.440]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    23.440] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[    23.440]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    23.440] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[    23.440]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    23.440] (WW) The directory "/var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType" does not exist.
[    23.440]    Entry deleted from font path.
```

It also tries to load the modules nv and nvidia a few times but fails each time because the modules do not exist so I'm guessing I'll have to install the modules. It looks like it eventually uses the module nouveau

```
[    23.473] (II) NOUVEAU driver Date:   Wed Sep 12 13:42:43 2012 +0200
[    23.473] (II) NOUVEAU driver for NVIDIA chipset families :
[    23.473]    RIVA TNT        (NV04)
[    23.473]    RIVA TNT2       (NV05)
[    23.473]    GeForce 256     (NV10)
[    23.473]    GeForce 2       (NV11, NV15)
[    23.473]    GeForce 4MX     (NV17, NV18)
[    23.473]    GeForce 3       (NV20)
[    23.473]    GeForce 4Ti     (NV25, NV28)
[    23.473]    GeForce FX      (NV3x)
[    23.473]    GeForce 6       (NV4x)
[    23.473]    GeForce 7       (G7x)
[    23.473]    GeForce 8       (G8x)
[    23.473]    GeForce GTX 200 (NVA0)
[    23.473]    GeForce GTX 400 (NVC0)
```

Any help in the right direction would be great as this isn't really an area I'm particularly strong with.

If there are any parts of the log files which might help please let me know and I'll paste them in

Comment: You mean *sleep* (suspend to ram), which is what a laptop with the lid down does, and not *hibernate* (suspend to disk) which is quite different -- it requires no power or battery at all.